# Can I omit "that" in the following case?

Tags: conjunctions

> She had eyes so far apart from each other **that** looking at them made me feel dizzy.

Can I omit the that in this case? Why and why not?

Comment: Notice that the subordinate clause *"looking at them made me feel dizzy"* is a declarative content clause, which could be used as a standalone sentence. That subordinate clause is licensed by the use of the word *"so"* in the main clause; notice how your example becomes ungrammatical without the "so": *"She had eyes far apart from each other that looking at them made me feel dizzy"*. For your example, the subordinator "that" is probably necessary to prevent the reader from mis-parsing the sentence as it is being read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> She had eyes so far apart from each other **that** looking at them made me feel dizzy.

No, you cannot drop the *[subordinating conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Subordinating_conjunctions)* **that** here. A subordinating conjunction is necessary to connect the two parts of the sentence.

Sometimes a subordinating conjunction can be dropped, but not in this case. Usually we omit a subordiating conjunction after a "[reporting verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_reporting_verbs)" like **to tell, learn, discover, feel** etc.:

> She had eyes so far apart from each other! I *told* her (**that**) they made me feel dizzy. I really *felt* (**that**) they made me dizzy.

Had it been a [relative pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun), you also could've dropped it:

> I felt dizzy looking into those beautiful eyes (**that**) she had.

Here, we can omit the relative pronoun **that** because it serves as the object of the relative clause "that she had".

> She had what? She had [that]. (**She** is the subject, **that** is the *object*)

Comment: How about "She had eyes so far apart from each other **comma** looking at them made me feel dizzy." ?

Comment: @Stephie - I thought about it, but first concentrated on telling the standard reasons for omission. Would the use of a comma to split the sentence count as omission? If yes, you can post your own answer. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle How about? "I realized (that) I couldn't..." Can I drop the "that" in this case?

Comment: @alexchenco - yes, because **realize** [is a reporting verb](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Mjrj21zryWMC&lpg=PT74&ots=HPkTjlYqTv&dq=reporting%20verb%20%22realize%22&hl=ru&pg=PT74#v=onepage&q=reporting%20verb%20%22realize%22&f=false)