# Omitting 'that' is acceptable in written form?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, reported-speech

1. You said **you did not know him**.
2. You said ***that*** **you did not know him**.

Apparently , while conversing , both are acceptable but while writing formally are they? Or is it the case that  the two fall under two different structures? Like in  the first one *you did not know him* is the noun clause to a transitive verb and the second one shows the transformation from *direct speech* to *indirect speech* and that way both are correct , is it? But noun clauses do require the conjunction *that* don't they ?

Answer (score 1):

In 'Practical English Usage', Michael Swan says "We can often leave out the conjunction *that*, especially in an informal style". So even in formal style, we can often leave it out (but less often than informal style).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the word *that* in your example because it's followed by a reporting verb.

Details and in the answer to [another similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46239/can-i-omit-that-in-the-following-case?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

A general rule for formality is that the more "optional" words you use in a sentence, the more formal it is.  There are many such "optional" words.  However, these "optional" words may be required if your listener becomes confused.

One thing to be careful of is that "formal" is not the same as "polite".  Depending on the circumstance, being "too formal" can be very rude.  As an English Language Learner, however, people will typically forgive you of most "formality level" mistakes.