# He was so angry that he could not speak. (so, that)

Tags: conjunctions, optional-that

> He was so angry that he could not speak.

> He was so angry he could not speak.

We learn the 'that' is optonal.

But I wonder if there is any nuance difference between w/ that or w/o that.

For example, "so angry that he could not speak." the 'that' is like 'thus' or 'therefore'?

Also wonder if the flow of interpretation with so' and 'that' mixed together is forwarding or backwarding
:

so angry to the extent that he could not speak(backward flow <-)

so angry and due to this he could not speak(forward flow ->)

ps. This question is not related to the omission of 'that' which is optional but is related to the 'so' and 'that' in a sentence.

Comment: "He was so angry he could not speak." This sentence seems strange to me.

Comment: The presence or absence of the relativiser ***that*** makes no difference in your context. In some more complex contexts it *might* be better to include it to help the reader / audience parse the text, but generally speaking it's irrelevant. Your "forward / backward" ideas are spurious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omission of “that” (in this text).](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56579/omission-of-that-in-this-text) Also [Can "THAT" be omitted here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145893/can-that-be-omitted-here) and others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi, your link does not addres 'so', 'that': they only deal 'that'

Comment: The word ***so*** is syntactically irrelevant to the presence or absence of ***that***. The difference is just that *She was annoyed [that] she hit me* means she was cross with herself ***because she hit me***, whereas *She was **so** annoyed [that] she hit me* means she hit me ***because of her high level of annoyance*** (for some unspecified reason).

Comment: Check [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=so+cold+it+froze%2Cso+cold+that+it+froze&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) for ***so cold [that] it froze***. As you'll see, both versions have remained equally common for at least a century. And I assure you it wouldn't make any difference to the meaning in most if not all matching instances there, if you reversed the choice about including ***that***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your explanaiton 'the word so is syntactically irrelevant to the presence or absence of that' is helpful a lot.

Comment: In *some* cases most native speakers will agree [that] it's much better to include the word "that" in this kind of "relativizer / pronoun" construction. But I'm pretty sure it's *always*  just a stylistic choice. And frankly, I don't think it's worth getting too bogged down in trying to understand exactly what factors influence a native speaker's decision to include "that" or not. Personally, I have no opinion about its use in the first sentence in this comment (and I wouldn't care one way or the other about what anyone else thinks of it either! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no added inference from including 'that'. Sometimes it can be omitted, but sometimes it cannot.

We use the word 'that' in examples like yours to introduce a '*clause of effect*' - a clause that tells us the *consequences* of an action. It is only necessary if omitting it would cause confusion.

For example, "*I was so scared I screamed*" could sound like you were scared of the possibility that you had screamed. To indicate that screaming was a consequence of being scared it is necessary to say "*I was so scared **that** I screamed*".

In your example, "*he was so angry he could not speak*" could sound like he was unable to speak, and that made him angry. To make it clear you mean the inability to speak was a consequence of the anger, you need to introduce the clause with 'that'.

You'll notice that if you omit the word "so", the meaning of these is unambiguously reversed. "*He was angry he could not speak*" would *definitely* mean that his anger was over his inability to speak, rather than unable to speak *because* of his anger. But as "so" can be used in isolation as an intensifier (eg "I am so angry!") that it alone is not always enough to make it clear a clause of effect will be coming along.

Comment: To say it's a 'clause of effect' is misleading since it implies that it's an adjunct, which it isn't. It's a complement in clause structure licensed by the "so" that modifies "angry".  See my answer for the semantics.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two versions of the sentence. Including or omitting the "that" does nothing disambiguate the sentence, but it is unlikely that it would need disambiguation anyway.

Including the "that" would be more usual in written English, and omitting the "that" a little more usual in spoken English where rhythm and emphasis would clarify meaning. That is all.

Additionally, native speakers are likely to prefer the contraction (couldn't) to the full version (could not).

Comment: Good with double GG

Answer (score 0):

> *He was so angry (that) he could not speak.*

Grammatically, the content clause "(that) he could not speak" is an 'indirect complement' licensed by the "so" that is modifying "angry".

"That" has no effect on the meaning; it's just a meaningless subordinator that is omissible under the conditions that apply to content clauses generally.

Semantically, "so" indicates degree/extent and the content clause has a resultative meaning that can be brought out by a gloss such as "The result of him being as angry as he was that he couldn't speak".

Comment: 'that he could not speak' is a subordinate clause which belongs to (noun, adjective, adverb clause?) Or just content clause? Can we classify it as noun, adjective, or adverb clause? In my perspective, the 'that' just looks like a conjunction 'and'.

Comment: @gomadeng  No: the classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.  "That he could not speak" is a declarative **content clause** and its function is **complement** in clause structure. "That* is a **subordinator** (your conjunction), but "and" is a coordinator, so there is no similarity between the two.

Answer (score -3):

Putting both sentences into Google, inside quotation marks so they'd be matched exactly to text, nets us 99,600 results for "that he could not speak" and only 28,400 returns for "he could not speak."

This fits what seems to be the consensus that, while they are both correct, one is a markedly more common usage.

See a similar question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103758/omitting-that-is-acceptable-in-written-form) about whether or not it is acceptable to omit conjunction like "that". (Spoiler: generally it is acceptable in informal speech.)

Comment: This does not answer the question. Can you say why they are both correct, other than some people on the internet have said it so it must be?

Comment: @Astralbee: Note that I did link a discussion from *this* site on exactly that question which covers it in detail. There is no point in adding a redundant answer.

Comment: You're right, there is no point in adding a redundant answer. If you think it is a duplicate you should vote to close it as such, citing the link.

Comment: @Astralbee I think in this case, the question is which is the more common usage, which is why I tried to quantify it by looking up specific cases. Even though "that" is a very commonly omitted word, it seems that, in this <i>particular</i> case, using "that" is more common.

Comment: I am not interested in more 'common' usage but interested in any possible difference with or without 'that' in terms of being used together with 'so'.

Comment: @gomadeng: You can check here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175237/omitting-that-is-so-that
Generally, "that" when used as a conjunction can be omitted when speaking informally, even when part of a "so...that" construct, but "so" would always need to remain.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your Google search terms don't really tell us anything at all. It stands to reason that if Google (Internet *or* Books search) really gave accurate estimates, there would *have* to be far more instances of "he could not speak" than of "**that** he could not speak", because every instance of the shorter string would *also* be counted within occurrences for the longer string. But what happens is Google isn't really doing a full "search and count". It just increases its guesstimate when it sees an extra "function word" *(**that**)*, because it knows such function words are ***really common***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's actually not how it works. If you searched without quotes, that would be accurate, but when you search a quoted string it is returned exactly. If you stopped to think about it for a moment, you'd see that it's impossible for me to get those results if that wasn't the case.

Comment: You're mistaken. I don't know how you got your figures - Google *Internet* estimates 4.4 *million* hits for "that he could not speak", and 15 million for the same without "that". Google *Books* no longer gives estimated totals, but there are at least 20 pages with 10 results per page for both strings. Perhaps if your default Google searches aren't in English that will explain the discrepancy, but the *logical* point I made cannot be disputed.